# Angular: service and ngrx return undefined

Tags: angular, service, ngrx-store

I am learning Angular, DI, Services and Ngrx and I have an issue that I cannot understand

When I log this.getBase() and this.baseRateSaving I got the value in my console but when I tried to inject it in my string interpolation I get undefined.

I tried without the getbase() method so with the this. baseRateSaving but my editor tells me 'Property 'baseRateSaving' is used before its initialization'

here is the code:

```
import { BodyCard, HeaderCard, IconDetails } from '@fortuneo/components/src/app/components/card/card.model';
import { CardsOptionsContextService } from './cards-options-context.service';
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { subscriptionSelector } from '../../../store/subscription/subscription.state';
import { savingsParametersSelector } from '../../../store/parameters/parameters.state';
import { Subscription as RXSubscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../../../store/store.model';
import { Product } from '@fortuneo-models/subscription';

export interface CardOptions {
  id: string;
  iconDetails: IconDetails;
  headerCard: HeaderCard;
  bodyCard: BodyCard;
  context?: {}
}

@Injectable()
export class CardsOptionsService implements OnDestroy {
  products: Product[];
  baseRateSaving: number;
  private data$: RXSubscription;

  constructor(private cardsOptionsContext: CardsOptionsContextService,
              private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.data$ = combineLatest([
      this.store.select(subscriptionSelector),
      this.store.select(savingsParametersSelector)
    ]).subscribe(([subscription, savingsParameters]) => {
      this.products = subscription.products;
      this.baseRateSaving = savingsParameters.baseRate;
    });
    console.log(this.baseRateSaving);
    console.log(this.getBase());
  }

  getBase() {
    return this.baseRateSaving;
  }
}
...
...
      headerCard: {
        title: '<h2 class="title">Livret +</h2>',
        subTitle: `<p class='subtitle'>Taux de base : ${this.getBase()}% bruts(2)</p>`
      },
```

I am really lost

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since i programmed with angular, i could be wrong but could you try to do it with ngOnInit instead of the constructor. You should look at the lifecycle of angular.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.logIt(`OnInit`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an `@Injectable()` class you can't put the getBase() directly.

put the headerCard variable in the component that you have created and from there you need to inject CardsOptionsService in the constructor and call getBase().

```
@Injectable()
export class CardsOptionsService {
  products: Product[];
  baseRateSaving: number;
  private data$: RXSubscription;

  constructor(private cardsOptionsContext: CardsOptionsContextService,
              private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.data$ = combineLatest([
      this.store.select(subscriptionSelector),
      this.store.select(savingsParametersSelector)
    ]).subscribe(([subscription, savingsParameters]) => {
      this.products = subscription.products;
      this.baseRateSaving = savingsParameters.baseRate;
    });
    console.log(this.baseRateSaving);
    console.log(this.getBase());
  }

  getBase() {
    return this.baseRateSaving;
  }
}
```

this service you need to inject to your component(Dont use component life cycle hooks(OnInit, OnDestroy) in your service).

```
@Component({ selector: 'header' })
class HeaderComponent implements OnInit () {

  headerCard: {
    title: '<h2 class="title">Livret +</h2>',
    subTitle: `<p class='subtitle'>Taux de base : ${this.base}% bruts(2)</p>`
  },
  constructor(private cardsOptionsService: CardsOptionsService) {}
  get base() {
    return this.cardsOptionsService.getBase();
  }

}
```

To convert string to html you need DomSanitizer.
Please refer below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-safehtml

Comment: Thanks for your respond,
I would like to leave the header variable inside the service
I can get the value of baseRateSaving in my console but it is undefined in this line: 
```
subTitle: `<p class='subtitle'>Taux de base : ${this.base}% bruts(2)</p>`
```

Comment: Ok. instead of using getBase() in your service can you use 
`get base() { return this.baseRateSaving; }` in your service?

Comment: thanks for this idea but it does not work. 
I found a solution: 
I moved the code in the constructor into a new service and called it that way: 
        subTitle: `<p class='subtitle'>Taux de base : ${this.cardOptionsUtils.baseRateSaving.toString()}% bruts(2)</p>`
and it works. 
now if someone can tell me why the first solution was not working, I will be gratefuk :)